# Why is SQL Server's SOUNDEX giving me inconsistent results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, soundex

Can someone provide some insight on why the SOUNDEX is giving different results when certain characters are capitalized vs lower case? From what I read online, SOUNDEX ignores case but I am getting different results and can't wrap my head around what would cause the differences. I can't mimic this example with are word like `GUTTHRE`.

```
Query                                  Result
select SOUNDEX('JESCHKE')              J200      <-- 200
select SOUNDEX(LOWER('JESCHKE'))       J220
select SOUNDEX('Jeschke')              J220
select SOUNDEX('jeschke')              J220
select SOUNDEX('JESChKE')              J220
select SOUNDEX('JESCHke')              J200      <-- for some reason capitalizing 'H' changes the result to 200
select SOUNDEX('jescHke')              J200      <-- 200
```

Any ideas why the values don't match?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm using Azure SQL Server v12.0

Comment: _[SOUNDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql) is collation sensitive._ But the docs don't describe exactly how collation affects the result.

Comment: Im having the same issue!

Comment: @AlwaysLearning so it looks like case could be part of the collation sensitivity.. when I read that I was only considering order and accents.

Comment: Btw, the correct result is J200

Comment: The reference for the soundex rules strongly suggests that the case of the characters does not matter:  https://www.archives.gov/research/census/soundex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) states:

> "two letters with the same number separated by 'h' or 'w' are coded as
> a single number"

So I think this applies when you are using a lowercase "h" hence the S is coded as a 2 and all the other characters would encode to 2 and are ignored as per:

> If two or more letters with the same number are adjacent in the
> original name (before step 1), only retain the first letter

I suspect that because the H is capitalised it resets this rule so that the following k is then coded as another 2.